# SequelizeDatabaseError: отношение "users" не существует

Tags: база-данных, node.js, sequelize.js

Пишу на Node.js использую библиотеку Sequelize, при создании нового 
пользователя вылетает ошибка SequelizeDatabaseError: отношение "users" не существует, что мне делать?